Location-dependent limit_req burst rate for same limit_req_zone?
I would like to use the same limit_req_zone (i.e. the same request rate) across various locations, but with different burst values for limit_req. The following configuration should be able to serve 2 pages, and up to 10 supporting assets for a page in a single burst. It tests ok, but is this the right way to do it, or would I need two different limit_req_zone directives?
http {
    limit_req_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=lr_zone:10m rate=1r/s;
    #...
    server {
        #...
        location / {
            limit_req zone=lr_zone burst=2 nodelay;
            #...
        }
        location ~ ^/(css|fonts|images|pdf)/ {
            limit_req zone=lr_zone burst=10 nodelay;
            #...
        }
    }
}


According to the ngx_http_limit_req module source code, as far as I could understand it, burst and delay=x/nodelay values are parameters of a particular limit_req directive, not the shared memory zone. Most likely this is the right way to solve your task.

Ivan Shatsky confirmed my assumption regarding the usage of different burst values while referring to the same limit_req_zone.
